# How to get attachments from an email using the Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: spring-boot, parameters, microsoft-graph-api, email-attachments, microsoft-graph-mail

I use the Spring Boot framework to develop a program that allows me to obtain the attached files of an email, but there is a code according to the Microsoft page that says that by means of the following code you can obtain the properties of the attached files, which is the following.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

Attachment attachment = graphClient.me().messages("AAMkADA1M-zAAA=").attachments("AAMkADA1M-CJKtzmnlcqVgqI=")
    .buildRequest()
    .get();
```

The doubt that I have is precisely what should be passed as parameter to the message() method, that according to this is passed "AAMkADA1M-zAAA=" according to an example that Microsoft Graph raises, but what is it? Is it the id of the tenant? or what is it?

In addition I also have doubt is in the parameter that happens in the attachments() method, really that `AAMkADA1M-CJKtzmnlcqVgqI=` What is it? What should be passed there?

I would like to know in those parameters what should be passed and how to obtain them to pass them?

What I expect from this code that Microsoft Graph proposes is to be able to obtain the attached files of an email, but according to that you must pass some parameters that I do not know and that I have already read on the web page and I have not found what those parameters that are passed in message() and attachments() refer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get attachments of a message you need to know the message id and the attachment id.

- List messages

```
MessageCollectionPage messages = graphClient.me().messages()
        .buildRequest()
        .select("id,sender,subject,hasAttachments")
        .get();
```

- Select the message and use it's id to get list of attachments

```
AttachmentCollectionPage attachments = graphClient.me().messages({message_id}).attachments()
    .buildRequest()
    .get();
```

- Select the attachment

```
Attachment attachment = graphClient.me().messages({message_id}).attachments({attachment_id})
    .buildRequest()
    .get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now with getting the attachments I am already seeing the information on it. The only thing I would be missing is to know how to download those attachments but there I will keep exploring, thanks for your help.